How to generate a pdf using the print view using js
Okay so i have a webpage that is different when i click print. I can save the page to pdf using the print function. This looks good.
The problem is, i need to do this using js. I have a button (download as pdf) that should download the page exactly as shown in the print view.
Is this even possible? Is there a way to only use the print styling?
Hopefully anyone can help :D

Easiest way to do this would be to call window.print() when the button is clicked. That will open up the print dialog and the user can save it to PDF themselves.
